# Mixpanel Custom FCMreceiver

Tags: android, mixpanel

I am using mixpanel for push notifications & wanted to customize my notification icon. While searching for a solution I found custom GCMReceiver being used. Has anyone created custom FCMReceiver? If so please share.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the mixpanel library to version 5.5.1 and follow these instructions https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-android/issues/586#issuecomment-470721319

You can use your own FCMReceiver class which you register in the manifest and pass every `RemoteMessage` you get via `onMessageReceived` to Mixpanel as shown below

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    if (remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("mp_message")) {
        MixpanelFCMMessagingService.showPushNotification(getApplicationContext(), remoteMessage.toIntent());
    }

    // Do something else with other providers here
}
```